# rails 4 HABTM relation and extra fields on join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, entity-relationship, has-and-belongs-to-many

What I have (pseudo code):

```
model Document
    column :title
    HABTM  :users
model User 
    column :name
    HABTM  :documents
```

Document has users (being approvers for document, either approve or not), and in this context join table should have extra column approved for each user.

```
jointable
    user_id, document_id, approved
    1      , 1          ,    true
    2      , 1          ,    false
```

What I want is basically:

```
contract.approvers => returns users but with possibility to =>
contract.approvers.first.approve(:true) => and it updates JOINtable approve column to TRUE.
```

Answer right for this situation is optional, will appreciate advises on schema too (or maybe i should use other type of relation?).

Comment: A join table is only that. If you want columns on the object that joins you'll need to look into the [has_many through](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) relation. My gut tells me neither HABTM nor has_many through are the right relation for this situation. I don't know that I understand enough to suggest something better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HABTM has been deprecated a while ago, I think it is just a reference to has many through now.

Either way

```
join table name = DocumentReview

Document 
  has_many :document_reviews
  has_many :users, through: :document_reviews

User
  has_many :document_reviews
  has_many :documents, through: :document_reviews
```

I don't understand how contract fits into this, i think you are saying that a document is a contract?

I would put the approve method in a separate class

```
class DocumentSignOff

  def initialize(user, document)
    @document_review = DocumentReview.find_by(user: user,document: document)
  end 

  def approve!
    #maybe more logic and such
    @document_review.udpate(approved: true)
  end
end
```

end